# Ruby on rails prevent serializer nest json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it's a simple question

I have a controller

```
class Api::ColorsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    colors = ProductCustom.where(product_id: params[:product_id], wheel_id: params[:wheel_id])
    render json: colors, each_serializer: ProductCustomsSerializer, adapter: :json, root: "data"
  end
end
```

ant two serializers

```
class ProductCustomsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  belongs_to :color, serializer: ColorSerializer
end

class ColorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :color
end
```

The response is fine but I'm getting nested objects. how can I prevent that?

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "color":{
            "id":11,
            "color":"green"
         }
      },
      {
         "color":{
            "id":12,
            "color":"blue"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

what I want

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":11,
         "color":"green"
      },
      {
         "id":12,
         "color":"blue"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your controller name suggests and the output you are looking for it seems to indicate the outcome is to serialize `Color` objects not `ProductCustom` objects.

If that is the case based upon the `params` your controller is receiving and assuming there is a `belongs_to` relation from your `ProductCustom` to `Color` on your ActiveModel you may want to try:

```
class Api::ColorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Query for the desired ProductCustoms objects and include the associated
    # Color objects. From the result set, map the Color objects into the array
    colors = ProductCustom
      .includes(:color)
      .where(product_id: params[:product_id], wheel_id: params[:wheel_id])
      .map(&:color)

    # You many want to add a trailing .uniq to the above if several ProductCustom 
    # use the same Color and you don't want duplicates.

    # Note, Rails should be able to determine the serializer to use but you
    # can always specify `each_serializer: ColorSerializer` if you really want
    render json: colors, adapter: :json, root: "data"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the complete explanation.